# MSXML2.XMLHTTP , Method 'open' of object 'IServerXMLHTTPRequest2' failed

Tags: vb6, msxml2

```
 Dim objHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
 Set objHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

 With objHTTPRequest
    .Open MethodName, strRequest, Asynchronous, strUserName, mstrPassword
    '___________more code here___________
 End with
```

I am trying to create a serverConnection object by getting the input parameters from the user using a visual basic form.  When run the code, I am getting the following error when executing the above code part. I am working on a word add-in and this error is only occurring when I run the code through vb and the created .dll for the product is working properly with Word.

> The following error occurred while submitting this request to a server: Method 'open' of object 'IServerXMLHTTPRequest2' failed
>   The server address() may be incorrect

in here,

```
strRequest= "/api/a1/Properties"
```

If anybody could, Please tell me why is this happening. Because of that error, I am unable to debug the code for further modifications.

Comment: That's a relative URL, what would it be relative to? -  you need a fully qualified one ...

Comment: Does the HTTP request object have any error status properties? Might give more information. Are there server logs you could check to see what is different in the two scenarios?